Adding user to group not taking effect until restart
Logging out and then in doesn't work!
I want to add a user to a group. So I do one of the thousands of ways to add the user to the /etc/group file (say, sudo adduser user group). I then have to do something for this change to reflect in the actual permissions.
All standard answers say "log out and then in again". This does not work. The user still gets the old permissions. The only way that does work is to reboot the machine.
I'm sure there is some systemd...  command that will cause the new permissions to take effect next session without a full reboot, but I have not been able to find it.
System is Ubuntu 24.04.

In Linux, when you do a permission change, you often have to restart the service that uses that permission.

You must always restart the service when you do a permission change, this step cannot be ignored or worked arround

The "service" is the user's session. Restarting it typically means logging out and in again. The problem is that this doesn't work. Only restarting the whole system works.


The "service" is the user's session. Restarting it typically means logging out and in again. The problem is that this doesn't work. Only restarting the whole system works.

A large chunk of your logon session is in fact running under a service: the systemd "user manager" aka user@<uid>.service, which is started outside of your session's process hierarchy. Programs that rely on D-Bus "demand activation" – such as GNOME Terminal, which has a client/server split – will inherit credentials from the service manager process (sometimes by way of dbus-daemon) instead of your gnome-session process.
(There is a mechanism to forward environment variables such as DISPLAY to the service manager and to D-Bus, but that can't be done for group memberships.)
You're probably seeing one of these:

The same service manager is shared across all of your logon sessions – not only the graphical one. If you have any inbound SSH connections, for example, they will keep the service manager alive across GUI logouts.

With recent systemd versions, the service manager is no longer stopped immediately after last session close – in default configuration there is a 10 second idle timer before that happens. Logging in too fast might cause the old manager process to continue running for the new session.



This second point is probably it. I'll test it.

Confirmed! Logging out and immediately back in does not add me to the group, but waiting about 15 seconds does. Thank you!

Thanks! I was having the issue of getting a new group membership even after switching to multi-user.target (or even rescue.target); A systemctl restart user@1000.service did the trick (replace 1000 with your uid)
